# Make `hostname -f` return fully qualified hostname

Tags: terminal, command-line, dns

How can i make `hostname` (i.e. the unix commandline tool `hostname`, invoked in terminal) return a hostname including the domain information?

At the moment, `hostname`, `hostname -f` and `hostname -s` return the same name, all without the domain information, but `host <hostname>` returns the full hostname:

```
$ hostname
> jvf-imac
$ hostname -f
> jvf-imac
$ hostname -s
> jvf-imac
$ host jvf-imac                                                                                                                                                                                     
> jvf-imac.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.31
```

The question is not about how I can get the full hostname in general. Some scripts I use rely on `hostname -f` to get the fully qualified hostname, so I need to make `hostname -f` return the correct hostname. Anyone any idea?

## Updates

### System Overview

- System Version: OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
- Kernel Version: Darwin 14.5.0
- Computer Name: jvf_imac

### Content of resolv.conf (shortened)

```
domain fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

### DNS Setup (shortened)

```
$ scutil --dns                                                                                                                                                                                          
resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fritz.box
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.178.1
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa ...

...

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa ...

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fritz.box
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.178.1
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
```

Comment: In System Preferences > Sharing, what does t say the computer name is? I believe `hostname` gets the FQDN from there on OS X, whereas `host <hostname>` appears to query DNS (though I'm on 10.11…)

Comment: Forgive me, why is this helpful? The local machine name only gets an IP if connected to the network. The 'hostname' command is local, the 'host' command is network-based. Once you know the hostname you can ask DNS to resolve it for you.

Comment: I agree with agentroadkill, I don't see how this is useful to my question, which is not about changing the hostname but to get the commandline tool  `hostname` to display the correct, full hostname including domain information. The part about the output of the `host` tool was only to show that my network setup and DNS seems to be working correctly otherwise...

Comment: @jvf Please add your system version. I can't replicate the behavior of your system in Yosemite though I've enabled the (proxy-)dns setup of your Fritz!Box.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.10.5, newest Yosemite version

Answer (score 7):

OS X is different in this case in that it might change your settings when it gets a response from your router / DNS+DHCP.

If you aren't getting a FQDN out of hostname, you couod set a FQDN first.

The Mac tool is `scutil`

```
scutil --get HostName            # same as hostname
scutil --get LocalHostName       # same as hostname -s
scutil --get ComputerName
```

If you want **jvf-imac.fritz.box** then simply:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName jvf-imac.fritz.box
```

You could set the host name with `sudo hostname ...` as well and it wouldn't be wrong. If I were to guess, you probably have **fritz.box** in `/etc/resolv.conf` which is why the DNS lookup appends the domain name since you didn't specify one more fully.

Comment: Though the scutil part is an answer I would have given also as a work-around the second part is doubtful. Fritz!Box is a (german) home router which provides a DHCP and a (proxy-)DNS-server.  The standard domain name is fritz.box. Yesterday I setup a VM only connected to this router and I had no problems to get the fqdn of the Mac (=iMac.fritz.box) with hostname.

Comment: @klanomath You are certainly right if the end problem is really how to make some fritz.box service work, but you can set your host name to be whatever you want whether or not it resolves or matches what the rest of the world expects :-) However, unless the OP does the work to explain how they really want a larger question answered - perhaps leaving that for a new thread works? As you commented, the details from the OP are lacking for us to dig into the deeper question at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and help so far. Setting the hostname with scutil works as a workaround. Of course I would be interested in finding a more general solution. Quite possible that the problem involves the dns proxy of the fritzbox. I'm happy to provide any additional info needed. If it is indeed the case, that fritzbox is the culprit here I'm also happy to change the original question to reflect this!

Comment: @jvf I'd say start a new thread if you want to add more details. :). Simpler that way for everyone

Comment: What DNS servers do you have configured?  Can you list them?

Comment: @Allan I added the output out scutil --dns to the original question

Comment: @jvf You may install dnsmasq via homebrew or [bind](http://packages.menandmice.com/bind/macosx/10.7-10.10/) and configure your own DNS-server @ home. No GUI available though (except you own OS X Server or install a [WebGUI](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2011/04/web-interfaces-for-the-bind-dns-server/))