# How to find out fully qualified hostname in osX (Terminal / Swift)?

Tags: terminal, swift

i've checked several posts, for example -  ([Make `hostname -f` return fully qualified hostname](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202536/make-hostname-f-return-fully-qualified-hostname))

My apple machine is connected to the domain and i'm logged on with a domain user.
the thing is, that hostname command only gives me the machine name - but i cannot find the domain part.

This is also true if i use the command *host 'hostname'*.

any clearance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `scutil --set` as indicated in answer to the question you've linked to?

Comment: Set doesn't set the hostname? the --get doesn't retrieve anything. do i need to set the domain (that i should be already linked to) manually?